# How can I dynamically assign IDs to elements of a particular class using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at other questions, but none of them have really helped me.  I want to give IDs to a number of elements belonging to the same class without manually doing it.  Here is my code that isn't working:

```
$curelem = $(".item:first");

for (var $i=0; i < $(".item").length; ++$i){
    $curelem.attr("id", "item" + $i);
    $curelem = $curelem.next('a');
}
```

Is it some small syntax error, or am I going about it entirely wrong?

Comment: May I ask why? IDs with numbers are ---usually--- code smell.

Comment: In my HTML I've got a sidebar with <a>s in it, and when I click on one of these, I want to be able to show a specific div.  That's kind of obscure, I realize

Comment: So, the reason you're using IDs like that is that you want to bind these div elements to clicking on the `a`s? Why not use an explicit binding in your code? Alternatively, a worse but simpler and still better solution, you can store a `data-url` attribute on your `a` tags that contains a selector for the `div` elements you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery you can use jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function:

```
var i = 0;

$('.item').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id', 'item' + i);
   i++;
});
```

Comment: You should consider learning about the DOM API before suggesting `$(this).attr("id"` (creating a jQuery object for no reason).

Comment: `this.id = 'item' + i;` for one. Though I'm afraid the underlying issue here is much bigger. Sequential numeric IDs are the indication of bad design - usually they should be an array instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So you mean invoking `$(this)` creates the object, I thought the object was created as soon as `$('.item').each` was called... where can I read up on that?

Comment: @FernandoSilva glad you asked! in the source code! This is what `.each` does http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.each - it iterates through something based on index. jQuery indexes the elements of a selection so `.each` calls a function on each element of a selection. Each element is a DOM element selected with sizzle (the jQuery selector engine) or with querySelectorAll (brosers' native one) depending on the browser. So each element in `.each` is a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element) that has an `id` property already.

Comment: Well, my answer may not be ideal but at least I've learnt something. I'll leave it as it is in the hope that others will do the same.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  When I view the source created by the script, I don't see any id elements, and nothing happens when I try to getElementById

Comment: @jd182 the problem OP is having is [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) he thinks he wants to select all elements by class and add them numeric IDs where in practice what he _really_ wants is to either use `.eq` with an index or better yet - use arrays. Selectors (jquery and others) are only useful at the initialization phase of the application. Once you have everything in place there is no reason to query your own presentation. OP can assign the elements of the class into an array.

Comment: @brooks.johnson if you're using jQuery you should not have to use `getElementById` anyway. You can use `$("#"+id)` - but like I said - this is the XY problem - you can just keep the selection and then access it like an array: `var items = $(".item")` and then access elements through `var cur = items[2]; //the third item` which has the same type as what you get from `getElementById` anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if I assign the elements to an array, how will I know which element was clicked when the onClick happens?

Comment: @brooks.johnson you're the one  attaching the click handlers to them aren't you? :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think this definitely is a case of the XY problem.  I've decided not to assign IDs like this now, but all of this has helped me figure out different ways to do what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think you should post an answer and maybe some pointers as to why the others are missing the point. I did understand, but I feel it should be stated as an answer.

Comment: @FernandoSilva for that I'd need OP's actual HTML. The problem with sequential IDs builds up to "How do I structure UI in web development" which is _way_ beyond the scope of an SO answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item').each(function (i, el) {
    el.id = "item" + i;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
    this.setAttribute('id', "item" + i);
});
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from Andrew's from 5 minutes ago. Or Pat's from 6? Or jd182 from 8?

Answer (score -1):

Use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ to loop through elements:

```
$(".item").each(function( index, value ) {
  $(this).attr("id", "item"+index);
});
```

Comment: This is just like the two other answers except it is incorrect.